# How to disable javascript code in mobile version

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

I have a script of audioplayer, I need to replace it to `play/pause` icons in mobile version and I did it, but I need to disable `audioplayer.js` in mobile version. In computer version I need `audioplayer.js`, but in mobile No. How can I disable script? I tried to use this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(this).width() < 494) {
      $('#script').attr('src', '')
      console.log($('#script').attr('src'));
    }
    else {
      $('#script').attr('src', 'js/audioplayer.js');
      console.log($('#script').attr('src'));
    }
 })
```

but it did not help me. I need to disable script only in mobile version.

Full sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/n1w5huy0/2/)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 480px)").matches) {
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="js/audioplayer.js"></script>');
}
```

You can use this to prevent including `audioplayer.js` on mobile devices

Comment: it did not help( there are some problems with quotes